# Overloading prefix operators ++/-- globally

Tags: c++11, operator-overloading, global-functions

I can globally overload unary + and - operators like this:

```
#include <cstdint>

enum local_states_t
{
    LOCAL_STATE_A = 1,
    LOCAL_STATE_B,
    LOCAL_STATE_LIMIT,
};

typedef uint32_t state_type_t;

state_type_t operator-(local_states_t state) { return static_cast<state_type_t>(state | (1<<31)); }
```

Can I do the same for prefix ++/--? The problem here of course is how would the compiler know that it only needs to call these functions for local_state_t - types? Prefix operators don't have a dummy value..

Comment: `(state | (1<<31))` looks suspicious. I think you want to pull that outside the parenthesis, and make it `| 1UL<<31`

Comment: Can you show what you tried? Because I don't yet see the problem.

Comment: @MSalters: I want to overload prefix ++ to return a "flagged" uint32 (mark highest 3 bits with certain properties). I can do it with unary +/- but can I do it with ++/-- as well (prefix)?

Comment: Prefix `operator++` by convention changes its argument, i.e. an `local_states_t&` for your overload . You can't add `1<<31` to `local_states_t` since that is out of range. So that's why I don't see what you're trying to achieve. Overloading itself isn't the problem - compilers know how to call the right operator for a given argument.

Comment: @MSalters: Isn't enum = int? It would indeed cause an overflow but wouldn't the bit be set anyway? If I don't care about representation, does it matter if i take int over uint?
But anyway, what would the operator overload for ++/-- look like?

Comment: No. You can write `enum local_states_t : int` to fix the **underlying type**, but even then it's not exactly the same type as `int`. (And technically you need `long` for `1L<<31` but we'll overlook that). And I'd expect the overload to be declared as `local_states_t& operator++(local_states_t &);`

Comment: @MSalters: Ahh, so the overload is determined by being the return value of the ++ being a reference to the input object? But why did you use local_states_t& inside the brackets? Isn't that indicating postfix ++? Interesting info on enum! So when I make the underlying type uint32_t will it work then?

Comment: No, overload resolution as always is determined solely by the argument type. The **postfix** `operator++` is the one with a dummy: `local_states_t operator++(local_states_t &, int);`. Note the missing `&` on the return type. An underlying type of `unit42_t` is indeed enough to add `1<<31`, or you could just add a `LOCAL_STATE_FLAG==1L<<31` to the declaration

Comment: @MSalters: Right, thank you! I didn't grasp that the local_states_t parameter would appear in the overload at all, as it doesn't for class method operator overloads. But I can then go against the convention and use state_type_t as my return type as well ++ right?

Comment: Convention is for humans; your compiler won't complain about the return type.

Comment: @MSalters: I think that solves it. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(From the comments)

Yes - you can define `local_states_t& operator++(local_states_t &)`. Unlike classes, enums can't have members, so you need a free function.

You can also define it to return `state_type_t`, which is unusual but allowed.